# Converting String to Type class object

Tags: sql, types, parameters, casting

I have a table storing datatypes of all the parameters and another table with the parameter values. When I use this in C# console app, how do I create a Type[] with the types present in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear how you store the type in database. Assuming its the assembly qualified name (eg: System.String)

```
var types = new List<Type>();

foreach(var row in myTable.AsEnumerable())
{
   var typeName = row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
   types.Add(Type.GetType(typeName));
}

var array = types.ToArray();
```

Comment: @sharmi You can accept the answer if it helped by clicking the 'tick' mark infront of the answer